# Closing session as an exception was thrown from MINA

Tags: apache-camel, mina

I keep getting this message
[Mina2Consumer] Closing session as an exception was thrown from MINA
but no other information or exception is logged - the mina2 code suggests it is throwing a Camel Exception but is not getting logged anywhere.

I am using Camel 2.11.0 and Mina2 2.0.7

any help will be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was this improvement recently in camel-mina2 to ensure the root cause is included in the exception if a write failure happened: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-6970

Maybe applying that patch to your Camel to see if that helps you. Or wait for that fix to be released and upgrade Camel etc.